# dotnet malloc: Double free of object when calling DllImport function

Tags: .net, marshalling, dllimport

I have a C# program calling an external function.
The C Function is the following:

```
char *confd_ns2prefix(u_int32_t ns)
{
    struct schema *schema = find_schema(ns);

    if (schema != NULL)
        return (char *)schema->prefix;
    return NULL;
}
```

I have declared the function as follow:

```
[DllImport("libconfd.so", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern string confd_ns2prefix(UInt32 ns);
```

When calling twice the function, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(libconfd.confd_ns2prefix((uint)1826703833));
Console.WriteLine(libconfd.confd_ns2prefix((uint)1826703833));
```

I will get a double free error the second time:

ncm
dotnet(39827,0x11dd24dc0) malloc: Double free of object 0x7f8182037b20
dotnet(39827,0x11dd24dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

It looks like the marshaller is trying to free object twice, but I have no idea why... In fact, it should not even free it.

Any idea ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior#memory-management-with-the-interop-marshaler

Answer (score 0):

Actually all was explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior

> However, if you define the method as a platform invoke prototype,
>   replace each BSTR type with a String type, and call MethodOne, the
>   common language runtime attempts to free b twice. You can change the
>   marshaling behavior by using IntPtr types rather than String types.
>
> The runtime always uses the CoTaskMemFree method to free memory. If
>   the memory you are working with was not allocated with the
>   CoTaskMemAlloc method, you must use an IntPtr and free the memory
>   manually using the appropriate method.

I fixed as follow

```
[DllImport("libconfd.so", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr confd_ns2prefix(UInt32 ns);

public static  string confd_ns2prefix_w(UInt32 ns) {
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(confd_ns2prefix(ns));
}
```