# Double Free Problem on Microsoft Default Marshaling Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, clr, marshalling

According to Microsoft ["Default Marshaling Behavior"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior)

Quoted:

> For example, calling the following unmanaged method from a C++ DLL does not automatically free any memory.
> Unmanaged signature

C++

```
BSTR MethodOne (BSTR b) {  
   return b;  
}
```

> However, if you define the method as a platform invoke prototype, replace each BSTR type with a String type, and call MethodOne, the common language runtime attempts to free b twice. You can change the marshaling behavior by using IntPtr types rather than String types.

Had read this documentation few times, try to figure out what's happening undercover, and I do try coding the example to reproduce the error:

C++ dll:

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    
    
    extern "C"
    {
        __declspec(dllexport) BSTR __cdecl test_returnself(BSTR b)
        {
            return b;
        }
    }
```

C# signature and call:

```
[DllImport("Test_Csharp_Marshal.dll",CallingConvention =CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static string test_returnself(string b);
...
string asd = "hello world";
string kksk = test_returnself(asd);
```

Well, the problem is, this program works just fine, with an exit code 0

So here's the problem:

After reading this documentation, I made a "guess" to persuade myself to comprehend the mechanism of marshaller:

Managed side sends the input string and gets the return string. However, they are actually referenced to same object and thus CLR tries to free b twice.

However after reading more documentation and the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932365/free-unmanaged-memory-allocation-from-managed-code).

I think it works more like make copy of the input and make copy of the return value, and the return and input are actually two objects. So how does this "Double free objects" problem happen?

Also, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122557/dotnet-malloc-double-free-of-object-when-calling-dllimport-function)

He did run into that problem, and I also make a guess of the reason:

The char the function returns actually allocate by methods like Sysalloc, so CLR can free this type automatically while on the unmanaged side it has its own garbage collector and thus free it twice.

Correct me if I am wrong, as I do think it is not correct.

Comment: The example is fairly artificial, a C++ program cannot safely call this function either.  It will likewise call SysFreeString() twice.  That just doesn't generate any diagnostic, so it *seems* to work just fine.  As long as another thread isn't also creating strings, then you have an utterly undebuggable problem.  Golden rule: if the native code is broken then it doesn't get better when you pinvoke it.

Comment: @HansPassant Appreciated! But can you explain about the logic behind the twice SysFreeString() call: I mean, who and why? Does the marshaller call the SysAllocString at the unmanaged side and then try to free twice or something else? Also why it sees two objects, are they the input argument and the return value which acts like an temporary object?